# Is there any mantra that cures insomnia?

Tags: mantras, yoga, deity, sleep

I know that this is off topic,but YouTube comment sections are filled with the remarks of people about how they felt better/were transformed when they listened to the mantra in that video.

Is there such a mantra that helps a person sleep/cures insomnia?

I have a feeling that this is a silly question,though.

Comment: Can you give link to video?

Comment: Mantras are meant to activate mind. Sleep in south-west corner of your house with head in South or East direction.

Comment: @Proxy Check this out https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Cf-M3ZHTcl8

Comment: It's nothing related to any particular mantra. You will find such comments in all type of videos whether it is a mantra, a song or just a soothing sound. Anything which helps the mind relax will help in sleep.

Comment: @baba Yes,baba,true.Such comments are seen in most such videos.

Answer (score 1):

There are some mantras that extols devi as nidra in Durga Saptashati, probably those can help you to deal with insomnia.

> यया त्वया जगत्स्रष्टा जगत् पात्यत्ति योजगत् ।
> सोऽपि निद्रावशं नीतः कस्त्वांस्तोतुमिहेश्वरः ॥१२॥
> By You, (He Who is) the Creator of the World, the Destroyer of the World, He Who is the World Itself (i.e. the Preserver of the World), even Him (i.e. Vishnu), You have overpowered with Sleep; What (further) Praise can therefore be uttered by me now, O Ishwari?
> -Saptashati, Chapter 1.

> यादेवी सर्वभूतेषू निद्रारूपेण संस्थिता।
> नमस्तस्यै, नमस्तस्यै,नमस्तस्यै नमोनमः ॥९॥
> Salutations again and again to the Devi who abides in all beings in the form of sleep.
> -Saptashati, chapter 5

कलिकार्पणमास्तु ।

Answer (score 1):

There is a charm in Atharvaveda 4:5 for sleeping.

> सहस्रशृङ्गो वृषभो यः समुद्रादुदाचरत्। तेना सहस्येना वयं नि
> जनान्त्स्वापयामसि ॥१॥
>
> न भूमिं वातो अति वाति नाति पश्यति कश्चन । स्त्रियश्च सर्वाः स्वापय
> शुनश्चेन्द्रसखा चरन् ॥२॥
>
> प्रोष्ठेशयास्तल्पेशया नारीर्या वह्यशीवरीः । स्त्रियो याः
> पुण्यगन्धयस्ताः सर्वाः स्वापयामसि ॥३॥
>
> एजदेजदजग्रभं चक्षुः प्राणमजग्रभम् । अङ्गान्यजग्रभं सर्वा
> रात्रीणामतिशर्वरे ॥४॥
>
> य आस्ते यश्चरति यश्च तिष्ठन् विपश्यति । तेषां सं दध्मो अक्षीणि यथेदं
> हर्म्यं तथा ॥५॥
>
> स्वप्तु माता स्वप्तु पिता स्वप्तु श्वा स्वप्तु विश्पतिः ।
> स्वपन्त्वस्यै ज्ञातयः स्वप्त्वयमभितो जनः ॥६॥
>
> स्वप्न स्वप्नाभिकरणेन सर्वं नि स्वापया जनम् ।
> ओत्सूर्यमन्यान्त्स्वापयाव्युषं जागृतादहमिन्द्र इवारिष्टो अक्षितः ॥७॥

> The Bull who hath a thousand horns, who rises up from out the
> sea,
> By him the strong and mighty one we lull the folk to rest and.
> sleep. Over the surface of the earth there breathes no wind, there looks.
> no eye. Lull all the women, lull the dogs to sleep, with Indra as thy
> friend!mThe woman sleeping in the court, lying without, or stretched on
> beds, The matrons with their odorous sweets—these, one and all, we
> lull to sleep. Each moving thing have I secured, have held and held the eye
> and breath. Each limb and member have I seized in the deep darkness of
> the night. The man who sits, the man who walks, whoever stands and clearly
> sees Of these we closely shut the eyes, even as we closely shut this
> house. Sleep mother, let the father sleep, sleep dog, and master of the
> home. Let all her kinsmen sleep, sleep all the people who are round
> about. With soporific charm, O Sleep, lull thou to slumber all the folk.
> Let the rest sleep till break of day, I will remain awake till
> dawn, like Indra free from scath and harm.